# How to create list of horizontal image galleries in a vertical Listview in android..?

Tags: android

Thanks in advance..

```
I have a task like creating list of image (Horizontal)galleries in an vertical listview in android.
```

I spend so much time but i didn't get any idea on that.

For the required screen please check the link as a reference :

http://www.appbrain.com/app/pulse-news/com.alphonso.pulse.

So please help me by providing the logic..

Comment: Even I had a situation like this. There is no way you can use the normal gallery widget since its orientation cannot be changed. So what I did is I made a listview with imageView and passed values from a arraylist. This is the easiest way I believe.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an Adapter for your ListView, you can specify a row layout containing any views you like. I think, you can create a row layout containing a Gallery view too. Hope this helps.